# Filtering one Meteor collection based off the property of another Meteor collection

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm trying to build a site similar to Reddit. Here's the link to what I have [so far](http://edward_siteace.meteor.com/) and here's the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/xcexght4/1/) for the site. So if the user creates an account and clicks on one of the website links, it wills send the user to a webpage regarding the website with a comment form underneath it. When the user makes a comment and the clicks Save, their comment will appear at the bottom of the page.

The problem I'm having is that the comment posted appears on all detailed pages of the websites. For example, if the user were to click on the Google link and then post a comment on the page, and then go back and click on Coursera, the comment the user made would appear on the Coursera page as well.

Currently I have this code to render the comments into the comments_section template:

```
Template.comments_section.helpers({
  comments:function(){
    return Comments.find({});
  }
});
```

Is there a way I can pass the website id into the find method so that it filters out comments made on other website pages?

Answer (score 1):

You should chain every comment to that website:

**Create field `websiteId`**

```
Comments.insert({
  comment:comment,
  postedOn: new Date(),
  websiteId: Router.current().params._id
});
```

On you route

```
this.render('comments_section', {
  to: "section",
  data: function(){
    return Comments.find({websiteId:this.params._id});
  }
});
```

That should query comment with that website id

Let me know

**EDIT**

Instead query in router, try query from template:

```
Template.comments_section.helpers({
  comments:function(){
    return Comments.find({websiteId:this.params._id});
  }
});
```

Comment: `websiteId: Router.current().params._id` does insert the website id into the comments collection but the filter isn't filtering out the other comments

Comment: After commenting out that template function, clicking save when posting a comment only refreshes the page. The comment is shown. What adjustments do I need to make to my "comments_section" html template?

Answer (score 0):

Two options, really. The first is to what @yudap said above, but the other is to denormalize and add all your comments directly to the post document. Eg, your initial insert for a post would look like this:

```
Posts.insert({
  title: "this dog is a cat",
  link: "http://nickelodeon.wikia.com/wiki/CatDog",
  comments: []
});
```

Then whenever someone tries to insert a comment, you can do something like this:

```
Posts.update(this.params._id, {
  $push: {
    $each: [{
      content: "You're totally right, that dog is a cat",
      userId: Meteor.userId(),
      timestamp: new Date()
    }],
    $sort: { timestamp: 1 }
  }
});
```

Then you can fetch the post and all the related comments in a single go, if you want to.

Comment: How would I go about rendering out the comments array in html?